# Force npm local folder dependency to be updated each time grunt task is run

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

I'm building an NPM/grunt-based tool (we'll call it ProjectX) that is separated into two distinct NPM modules -- one for user-configurable content, the other for the core services.

The user-configurable project calls on the core services project as a dependency in its package.json:

```
// User Content project
{
  "description": "User-configurable content for ProjectX",
  "name": "px-user-content",
  "version": "0.0.1-alpha.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-check-dependencies": "^0.12.0",
    "grunt-subgrunt": "^1.2.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "px-core-services": "file:///Users/Me/Development/ProjectX/px-core-services"
  }
}
```

This works fine when running `$ npm install` from the User Config dir, copying the Core Services project into `px-user-content/node_modules/px-core-services`.

As I'm actively developing this project, I want to be able to have the dependency update itself automatically every time I run my User Config grunt project. Currently I'm using a delete task to delete the node module and reinstall it, but that takes a good 30 seconds to execute because it proceeds to reinstall *all* the other published dependencies.

Is there a simpler (speedier) way to force a local folder NPM dependency to update itself every time my grunt task runs? Or is there a way (hopefully without using a symlink) that I could point the core-services dependency to the dev folder?

Comment: add two tasks do a npm uninstall packagename, then install it again, run these tasks before the task that runs your application, does that make any sense?

Comment: Yeah - that's the problem though, is that it goes to re-install all of `px-core-services` dependencies too -- a 30s process at this point.

Comment: what about an old school delete / copy paste just for the single file you need (or the ones that need to be updated) by using grunt-exec?

Comment: Eeeeeewww.... but yeah, I might not have a choice

Comment: yeah it's like hammering the freaking file but that may do the trick! good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Jack's suggestion, ended up using [grunt-contrib-copy](/questions/tagged/grunt-contrib-copy) to copy just the files I needed:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    copy: {
        devProject: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '/Users/Me/Development/px-core-services/',
            src: ['Gruntfile.js', 'server.js', etc...],
            dest: 'node_modules/px-core-services/'
        }
    },
    checkDependencies: {
        this: {
            install: true,
            continueAfterInstall: true
        }
    },
    subgrunt: {
        ... 
    }
})
grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy', etc...])
```